# How to display ContextMenuTextItem over other components in Kivy

Tags: kivy

now i'm creating a GUI for application by kivy, and i have a problem as following:

When i click onto Title "Job", there is a menu, the problem is the menu is overlapped by other components (textinput...). How could i display this menu over textinput ? Please see picture for more details.

[Problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B9XO5.png)

```
    #: import main todo
    #: import ListAdapter kivy.adapters.listadapter.ListAdapter
    #: import ListItemButton kivy.uix.listview.ListItemButton
    Root:
        task_input: task_input_view
        task_list: tasks_list_view
        text_input: text_input
        BoxLayout:
            orientation: 'vertical'
            id: layout

            AppMenu:
               id: app_menu
               top: root.height
               cancel_handler_widget: layout
               AppMenuTextItem:
                    text: "Job"
                    ContextMenu:
                         ContextMenuTextItem:
                              text: "Open"
                              on_release: root.show_load()
                         ContextMenuTextItem:
                              text: "Save"
                              on_release: root.show_save()
                         ContextMenuTextItem:
                              text: "SaveAs"
                         ContextMenuDivider:
                         ContextMenuTextItem:
                              text: "Exec"

          BoxLayout:
               size_hint_y: None
               height: "40dp"

               TextInput:
                   id: task_input_view
                   size_hint_x: 70
               Button:
                   text: "Add"
                   size_hint_x: 15
                   on_press: root.add_task()
               Button:
                   text: "Del"
                   size_hint_x: 15
                   on_press: root.del_task()

          ListView:
              id: tasks_list_view
              adapter:
                    ListAdapter(data=[], cls=main.TaskButton)

         TextInput:
               id: text_input
               text: ''
```

Answer (score 1):

How to make this type of menu has more than one solution, but basically you need something that will be displayed on the top of each widget (or the widgets you want in background). This could be achieved in `BoxLayout`, but it's not efficient. Rather than Box, make it `FloatLayout` and add the widget that handles your menu(that panel) as the last widget - this way it'll be on top of every widget added before it and menu should behave like desired.

Comment: in BoxLayout it should be not able to put the menu widget as the last widget, if we want to put the menu at the top of window, because the widget position is controlled by this layout itself. I added a positive point to this answer for it saying that "make it FloatLayout and add the widget that handles your menu (that panel) as the last widget", yes we may set the menu widget as the last widget and put its position at the top of window.